How to check if user goes to a valid route when using Nextjs

i have a question, i've spend the past 2 hours looking for an answer on the web but i haven't find one.
well im using Nextjs with the new App router.
when a user navigate to an undefined route in app/api.  Ex: (localhost:3000/api/useer/1235) (userr= does not exist)
next will respond with a 404 html page which is correct, but instead of returning an html page and because its an api call  i would like to return a Json response to the user.
any help or suggestion is appreciated , Thank you.

I think you can make it by custom. For example, you're fetching a user by : id. So from the database response if the user doesn't exit you will get a message user does not exist and from the frontend, you will render the page based on the API response.

Sayedul Karim thank you for your suggestion, but i think you did not understand the situation, in this case i would like for the app to handle undefined routes something like a middleware that check routes, i mean what you're suggesting would be correct but after a user navigate to an existing route like GET /api/user which means a correct route then i would be able to fetch data from DB.

You can use a Catch All API Route/Optional Catch All API Route to handle all non-existent requests. Request pages that actually exist will take precedence over this route so it won't mess with your existing API routes.
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes#catch-all-api-routes

pages/api/post/[...slug].js matches /api/post/a, but also
/api/post/a/b, /api/post/a/b/c and so on.

Then put whatever JSON response you want in there.

Catch-all API did not help, so I ended up setting checkpoints in the middleware file. If a user tries to navigate to a route outside the routing list, a JSON response with status 404 will be returned. It may be a silly approach, but that's all I could think of for the moment until an expert in Next.js or one of its engineers comes to the rescue.
Thank you
